# Converting integer numbers to hh:mm:ss in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

I have a column of data that is in a data frame that is like this, these are hours but they do not all contain the same number of digits

```
0,
600,
1200,
1800,
0,
600, 
...
```

I would like to change this so it is in the format of `hh:mm:ss`. How do I do this?

Comment: so e.g., `1800` means 1800 hours?

Comment: I guess they're number of seconds.

Comment: show an example of what it is and how you want to be

Comment: @Ma0 yeah so its, midnight, six o clock, midday, six o clock etc

Answer (score 1):

The [`datetime` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time) is your friend and ally in this one.

```
import datetime


lst = [0, 600, 1200, 1800, 0, 600]

lst = [datetime.time(hour=x//100).strftime("%H:%M:%S") for x in lst]
# -> ['00:00:00', '06:00:00', '12:00:00', '18:00:00', '00:00:00', '06:00:00']
```

Answer (score 0):

a pandas version, making use of zfill and wrap:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [0, 600, 1200, 1800, 0, 600]})

# fill with zeros to always get 4 digits
# split into two parts, with : inbetween
# add the seconds as ':00'
df['hms'] = df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(4).str.wrap(2).str.replace('\n', ':') + ':00'

df['hms']
0    00:00:00
1    06:00:00
2    12:00:00
3    18:00:00
4    00:00:00
5    06:00:00
Name: hms, dtype: object
```